Vector Subspaces of "Light-Cone"
Consider $V=\mathbb R^n$ as a vector space. Define
\begin{equation}
L=\left\{v\in V:\sum_{i,j=1}^nv_i v_jB_{ij}=0\right\}
\end{equation}
where $B_{ij}$ is the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with $-1$ in the first $p$ entries and $+1$ in the next $q=n-p$ entries. $L$ is not a vector subspace of $V$. But what is the maximum dimension of subspaces of $L$ which are vector subspaces of $V$? It's at least one because there it at least one element of $L$ and it remains an element of $L$ when multiplied by a scalar.

You're looking for the maximal dimension of subspaces $W$ such that $v^TBw=0$ for all $v,w\in W$. For a symmetric, non-degenerate bilinear form $B$, this goes by the name of Witt index. It comes with a rather general theory of symmetric bilinear forms over field of characteristic $\ne2$, but for the case of a real symmetric bilinear form having signature $\sigma=(s^+,s^-,s^0)$ with $s^0=0$, the Witt index is $i(\sigma)=\min{s^+,s^-}$.

@SassatelliGiulio Great. Thanks!

A precisation. A subspace $W$ such that $v^TBw=0$ for all $v,w\in W$ is called isotropic. All maximal isotropic subspaces have the same dimension $i(B)$.
